# How to handle case sensitive in Angular. Binding data from FormControl to Model

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Express REST API to get date from SQL server. The data set field may be lower or Title case. But the FormGroup name are camelcase. I want to get the dataset from SQL server and need to bind to a TypeScript Class.

For example

```
class Person {
    public FirstName ;
    public LastName; 
}
```

In my Angular component I am using firstname and lastName as control

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.personForm =  this.fb.group({
      title:[''],
      firstName: [' ', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]] ,
      lastName: [' ',[ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]] 
});
```

How to set the value from the Form control to Person class instance ? it need to be both same ?

Also sometime when we get data from back end server (SQL Server) the fields may be firstname, lastname based on the stored procedure fetching the data.

Please help how to resolve this case sensitive issue in Angular.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue. Any solution to it?